# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, ibm-integration-bus

Using IIB 10.19 in Linux. I have developed an application to call HTTPs REST URLs through HTTP Request Node. In HTTP Request Node's SSL tab, currently 'Protocol' is TLS. In 'Allowed SSL Ciphers' and 'SSL Client Authentication Key Alias' fields, nothing written. 'Enable SSL Certificate Hostname Checking' and 'Enable Certificate Revocation List Checking' both are unchecked.

Without Certificate Installations, it was not working. Hence I have followed below steps to create keystores and associated them in Integration Server level where UFISBRK is my node and TESTEG is the server:

```
keytool -genkey -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keypass welcome101 -keystore /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/identity.jks -validity 365

keytool -export -alias localhost -file /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/localhost.cer -keystore /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/identity.jks -storepass welcome101

keytool -import -alias localhost -file /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/localhost.cer -keystore /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/trust.jks -storepass welcome101

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias thrifty -file /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/Thrifty.cer -keystore /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/trust.jks -storepass welcome101

keytool -list -keystore /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/identity.jks

keytool -list -keystore /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/trust.jks

chmod 777 /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/identity.jks

chmod 777 /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/trust.jks


mqsichangeproperties UFISBRK -e TESTEG -o ComIbmJVMManager -n keystoreFile -v /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/identity.jks

mqsichangeproperties UFISBRK -e TESTEG -o ComIbmJVMManager -n keystoreType -v JKS

mqsichangeproperties UFISBRK -e TESTEG -o ComIbmJVMManager -n keystorePass -v TESTEG::keystorePass

mqsisetdbparms UFISBRK -n TESTEG::keystorePass -u na -p welcome101



mqsichangeproperties UFISBRK -e TESTEG -o ComIbmJVMManager -n truststoreFile -v /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/trust.jks

mqsichangeproperties UFISBRK -e TESTEG -o ComIbmJVMManager -n truststoreType -v JKS

mqsichangeproperties UFISBRK -e TESTEG -o ComIbmJVMManager -n truststorePass -v TESTEG::truststorePass

mqsisetdbparms UFISBRK -n TESTEG::truststorePass -u na -p welcome101


mqsireportproperties UFISBRK -o ComIbmJVMManager -a -e TESTEG

mqsistop UFISBRK

mqsistart UFISBRK
```

But, still it is not working. Giving below error:

```
<Text>javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority, O="The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error</Text>
```

The Certificate I have Loaded and the Certificate mentioned in the Error are different. Also, I have checked this Go Daddy Group Certificate. It is not there in the trust store I have created. It is inside the default trust store in /home/mqm/acdm/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/security/cacerts
path.

I don't know, how the newly created trust store is getting ignored. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? What to do to resolve the issue?

-------------This portion is added later, current error log after broker restart--------------

```
( ['MQROOT' : 0x7fb94129e4b0]
  (0x01000000:Name):RecoverableException = (
    (0x03000000:NameValue):File                 = '/build/slot3/S1000_P/src/DataFlowEngine/MessageServices/ImbDataFlowNode.cpp' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Line                 = 1251 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Function             = 'ImbDataFlowNode::createExceptionList' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Type                 = 'ComIbmWSRequestNode' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Name                 = 'ThriftyService_MF#FCMComposite_1_3' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Label                = 'ThriftyService_MF.HTTP Request' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Catalog              = 'BIPmsgs' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Severity             = 3 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Number               = 2230 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Text                 = 'Node throwing exception' (CHARACTER)
    (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert               = (
      (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 14 (INTEGER)
      (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = 'ThriftyService_MF.HTTP Request' (CHARACTER)
    )
    (0x01000000:Name     ):RecoverableException = (
      (0x03000000:NameValue):File                 = '/build/slot3/S1000_P/src/WebServices/WSLibrary/ImbWSRequestNode.cpp' (CHARACTER)
      (0x03000000:NameValue):Line                 = 1147 (INTEGER)
      (0x03000000:NameValue):Function             = 'ImbWSRequestNode::evaluate' (CHARACTER)
      (0x03000000:NameValue):Type                 = '' (CHARACTER)
      (0x03000000:NameValue):Name                 = '' (CHARACTER)
      (0x03000000:NameValue):Label                = '' (CHARACTER)
      (0x03000000:NameValue):Catalog              = 'BIPmsgs' (CHARACTER)
      (0x03000000:NameValue):Severity             = 3 (INTEGER)
      (0x03000000:NameValue):Number               = 3162 (INTEGER)
      (0x03000000:NameValue):Text                 = 'WebService Request Exception' (CHARACTER)
      (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert               = (
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 12 (INTEGER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = '436f6e74656e742d547970653a20746578742f786d6c3b20636861727365743d7574662d380d0a486f73743a206c6f67696e2e746872696674797561652e61650d0a534f4150416374696f6e3a2022220d0a436f6e6e656374696f6e3a204b6565702d416c6976650d0a0d0a' (CHARACTER)
      )
      (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert               = (
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 12 (INTEGER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = '' (CHARACTER)
      )
      (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert               = (
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = '' (CHARACTER)
      )
      (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert               = (
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = '' (CHARACTER)
      )
      (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert               = (
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = 'GET /ThriftyAUHAirport/ThriftyAUHAirport.svc/ChargeCodesThrifty?Key=M28%4090R%40i%2A%40l24%2AE%2ASp3%406OT%40hsw9se36r HTTP/1.1
' (CHARACTER)
      )
      (0x01000000:Name     ):RecoverableException = (
        (0x03000000:NameValue):File            = '/build/slot3/S1000_P/src/WebServices/WSLibrary/ImbWSRequest.cpp' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Line            = 655 (INTEGER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Function        = 'ImbWSRequest::makeWSRequest' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Type            = '' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Name            = '' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Label           = '' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Catalog         = 'BIPmsgs' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Severity        = 3 (INTEGER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Number          = 3152 (INTEGER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Text            = 'A Web Service request has detected a SOCKET error whilst invoking a web service located at host &1, on port &2, on path &3.' (CHARACTER)
        (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert          = (
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = 'login.thriftyuae.ae' (CHARACTER)
        )
        (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert          = (
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 2 (INTEGER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = '443' (CHARACTER)
        )
        (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert          = (
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = '/ThriftyAUHAirport/ThriftyAUHAirport.svc/ChargeCodesThrifty' (CHARACTER)
        )
        (0x01000000:Name     ):SocketException = (
          (0x03000000:NameValue):File     = '/build/slot3/S1000_P/src/WebServices/WSLibrary/ImbSocket.cpp' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Line     = 1289 (INTEGER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Function = 'ImbSocketJNIManager::handleGeneralJavaException' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Type     = '' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Name     = '' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Label    = '' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Catalog  = 'BIPmsgs' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Severity = 3 (INTEGER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Number   = 3165 (INTEGER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Text     = 'An error occurred whilst performing an SSL socket operation' (CHARACTER)
          (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert   = (
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = 'connect' (CHARACTER)
          )
          (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert   = (
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = 'javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Jersey City, ST=New Jersey, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error' (CHARACTER)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

-------------This portion is added later, current error log after broker restart----------------------------

Comment: Himadri, are you able to call the endpoint configured in HTTP Request node using POSTMAN ?

Comment: Two things: 1) You say "Without Certificate Installations, it was not working.". What was the error there? It actually should work, because by default the Execution Group validates against the `cacerts` from the JRE. 2) When you create your own trust store for the TESTEG, the default `cacerts` from the JRE is not used anymore; so you have to add the Go Daddy CA to your TESTEG trust store.

Comment: @Rohan Yes it's working perfectly in postman.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann 1) The error is same like after installation of certificate. 2) There is a little misunderstanding Daniel. Go Daddy certificate was a pre installed certificate that was already there in cacerts. I have nothing to do with Go Daddy. I need to point to the certificate which is installed from Thrifty.cer file into my newly created trust.jks. Thrifty.cer is definitely not Go daddy certificate. But unfortunately, without picking up Thrifty Certificate from trust.jks, it is referring Go Daddy Certificate from cacerts. How?

Comment: Strange. Can you share more info about your `Thrifty.cer`, i.e. tell us the output of `openssl x509 -in /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/Thrifty.cer -text -noout | head -20`?

Comment: Note: First downloaded, then copied Thrifty.cer from windows desktop to Linux server through winscp

Comment: @Himadri , Himadri - the endpoitns certificat....import it in your jks store that you configured for IIB to use. follow this link to import. ==>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59351313/openssl-der-files-importing-into-java-keystore

Comment: @Himadri Your `Thrifty.cer` is not in PEM format, this is why my `openssl` command throws an error. Now I looked at this web page where you download the certificate. This has nothing to do with Go Daddy. So you must connect from IIB to somewhere else. Can you share the full exception stack? This will contain the URL you are trying to connect to.

Comment: @Rohan Thrifty.cer is already imported into trust.jks by this line ```keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias thrifty -file /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/Thrifty.cer -keystore /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/trust.jks -storepass welcome101```, still issue occurred. keytool command -that is ok na? or should I use openssl to download and import certificate? I'm having 0 knowledge on openssl commands, I'm sorry for that dear...

Comment: @DanielSteinmann..I bounced the broker again today..It still throws error, but a different error..I think it is now referring Thrifty.cer from Trust.jks correctly and stopped referring cacerts from JRE. Which is good. But the Thrifty.cer itself has the issue. Can you help me with the openssl commands to download and import thrifty certificate in Linux box itself? Also kindly refer the latest error stack in next comment.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann Daniel please refer "-------------This portion is added later, current error log after broker restart--------------" portion in my original post..due to size, I couldn't write the error in comment section, I had to edit the post.

Comment: Here an `openssl` command to retrieve the certs: `openssl s_client -showcerts -servername login.thriftyuae.ae -connect login.thriftyuae.ae:443  < /dev/null`. These are the two certs you have to add to your trust store.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielSteinmann for help..issue is resolved. I have little modified ur openssl command and downloaded the certificate by `echo -n | openssl s_client -connect login.thriftyuae.ae:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > thrifty.pem` and then imported that by `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias thrifty -file /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/thrifty.pem -keystore /home/mqm/TESTEG/Certificates/trust.jks`..restarted the broker..and it's working perfectly..but I didn't understand why same certificate downloaded from browser in DER encoded format - didn't work!!

Comment: Glad I could help. I also don't know why browser download does not work. I have seen cases where proxies break the SSL connection and don't give you real destination cert.